# OpenGL : Draw curve between 3 points

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, bezier

Basically I wish to draw a curve between 3 points in openGL as the below image indicates. I've found a couple of segments of code which would be useful for drawing a bezier curve using 4 points but for 3 points I've had really no success.

[image]

Comment: Note: a Bezier curve would not go through P2.

Comment: Look at http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/doc/Bezier-curves.html on how the control points, and mid-points are used to construct a Bezier curve. In your case you know the end points, and the mid-point `m5`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the definition of a Bezier curve you have the following formula (for each x, y component):

```
x(t) = (1-t)^3*p1x + 3*t*(1-t)^2*c1x + 3*t^2*(1-t)*c3x + t^3*p3x
y(t) = (1-t)^3*p1y + 3*t*(1-t)^2*c1y + 3*t^2*(1-t)*c3y + t^3*p3y
```

[image: Bezier Constructions]

In your case you know the mid point `(p2x,p2y)`. You can also assume that `c1x`  and  `c2x` have the same value; and that `c1y`  and  `c2y` also have the same value

So we have the following equations at t=0.5

```
p2x = (3/4)*c1x+(p1x+p3x)/8
p2y = (3/4)*c1y+(p1y+p3y)/8
```

which are solved for `c1x=c2x` and `c1y=c2y` with

```
c1x = c2x = -(p1x-8*p2x+p3x)/6
c1y = c2y = -(p1y-8*p2y+p3y)/6
```

to give the final Bezier equation to use in terms of points `(p1x,p1y)`, `(p2x,p2y)` and `(p3x,p3y)`:

```
x(t) =    (1-t)^3 *      [p1x]
     + 3*t*(1-t)^2 * [-(p1x-8*p2x+p3x)/6]
     + 3*t^2*(1-t) * [-(p1x-8*p2x+p3x)/6]
     +    t^3 *          [p3x]

y(t) =    (1-t)^3 *      [p1y]
     + 3*t*(1-t)^2 * [-(p1y-8*p2y+p3y)/6]
     + 3*t^2*(1-t) * [-(p1y-8*p2y+p3y)/6]
     +    t^3 *          [p3y]
```

**Summary**

Try the four control points

1. `( p1x, p1y )`
2. `( -(p1x-8*p2x+p3x)/6, -(p1y-8*p2y+p3y)/6 )`
3. `( -(p1x-8*p2x+p3x)/6, -(p1y-8*p2y+p3y)/6 )`
4. `( p3x, p3y )`

Here is an example I made with `p1=(0,0)`, `p2=(2,2)` and `p3=(4,-1)`. I calculated the following control points

1. `( 0, 0 )`
2. `( 2, 17/6 )`
3. `( 2, 17/6 )`
4. `( 4, -1)`

with the results shown below:

[image: Derive Plot]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a [Hermite spline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline#Finite_difference).